# jade output path directory using the makefile

Tags: html, makefile, pug

I'm using the [makefile](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#example-makefile) to compile jade file into html. How should I amend this line with jade options so that my ultimate index.html is one level up in the directory and not in the same folder as the jade files? Currently, I'm having the index.html inside the folder jade.

```
%.html: %.jade
    jade < $< --out $< --path $< --pretty > $@
```

I would want the folder structure to be like this:

```
|--jade
   |--index.jade
|--index.html
```

I do not want my folder structure to be like this:

```
|--jade
   |--index.jade
   |--index.html
```

my entire makefile includes:

```
JADE = $(shell find jade/*.jade)
HTML = $(JADE:.jade=.html)

all: $(HTML)

%.html: %.jade
    jade < $< --out $< --path $< --pretty > $@

clean:
    rm -f $(HTML)

.PHONY: clean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *all* html files to go into the directory one level up:

```
JADE = $(shell find jade/*.jade)
HTML = $(patsubst jade/%.jade, %.html, $(JADE))

all: $(HTML)

%.html: jade/%.jade
    jade < $< --out $< --path $< --pretty > $@
```

If you want `index.html` to go into the upper directory, but all other html files to go into `jade/`:

```
JADE = $(shell find jade/*.jade)
HTML := $(JADE:.jade=.html)
HTML := $(subst jade/index.html, index.html, $(HTML))

all: $(HTML)

%.html: %.jade
    jade < $< --out $< --path $< --pretty > $@

index.html: jade/index.jade
    jade < $< --out $< --path $< --pretty > $@
```

If there are *many* html files which should go into the upper directory, you can construct the `HTML` list any way you like, and then:

```
%.html: %.jade
    jade < $< --out $< --path $< --pretty > $@

%.html: jade/%.jade
    jade < $< --out $< --path $< --pretty > $@
```